# Palindromic Sentences using Stack in Java

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

The aim of the code is to return all palindromes ignoring punctuation and should be case insensitive.
The code can work out basic palindromes but i believe it's the punctuation that is problem.

I would like to know how to get this code to return a full sentence palindrome and also for it to return true if there is nothing but punctuation since that should display an empty string.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Palindromes {
    public static boolean isPalindromeSentence(String sentence) {
        Stack <String> p = new Stack<>();
        boolean c;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            c = Character.isAlphabetic(sentence.charAt(i));
            char a;
            if (c == true)  {
                a = Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i));
                p.push (a + "");
            }
            else if (c == false)    {
                i++;
            }
        }
        String reversed = "";
        while (!p.isEmpty())    {
            reversed += p.pop();
        }

        return sentence.equals(reversed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your algorithm, clean your input of all non letters and make it lowercase too:

```
sentence = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
```

---

A style plus bug-avoidance tip: Never compare a boolean in an `if` test, just use it as-is and avoid redundant `else` tests. Eg, instead of:

```
if (c == true)  {
    ...
} else if (c == false)  {
    ...
}
```

just

```
if (c) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Not only is this much clearer and cleaner, it avoids any chance of the nasty "accidental assignment" bug

```
if (c = true) { // oops! Compiles and executes, but silently assigns
```

Comment: thanks so much! I'm just starting to code so I'm not always comfortable with shortened/default value codes so i have a tendency to write out the whole thing. I will definitely keep this in my mind for future reference!